# How can I reorder every axis in ggalluvial?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to clean up the alluvian plot using ggplot. As you can see the graph I plot, all of the columns are in ascending order. I have tried to drag each cell by mouse, but it doesn't work. How can I customize order in every axis?
[The order of the left column is in ascending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSZZu.jpg)

If this is not possible in ggalluvial but possible in other packages, I'd like to know as well.

Thanks in advance.

My code to plot the graph :

```
exceldata <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/MENGL/Downloads/kuan1.xlsx",sheetName ="Sheet1" )     
dfdata = data.frame(exceldata)
dfdata

ggplot(data = dfdata,
       aes(
           axis1 = Tool.name,   
           axis2 = Core.network.model,
           axis3 = Evaluation.strategy,  
           axis4 = Published.year,
           y = freq
           )) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = PTM.type)) +
  geom_stratum( width = 0.5) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),
            size = 4,
            min.y = 1) +
  theme_void()
```

I have also attached a link towards the sample data.

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fBr6BJuWatcznKB58RM4Okf6tdBto0r9/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102065784261310303747&rtpof=true&sd=true`

Answer (score 0):

OP, you reorder axes the same way in `ggalluvial` that you would any other discrete axis or legend ordering in `ggplot2`: setting the levels of the factor.

Here's an example below modified from [an example in the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html#:%7E:text=The%20ggalluvial%20package%20is%20a,the%20feedback%20of%20many%20users.):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

df <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

ggplot(df, aes(y = Freq, axis1 = Survived, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Class)) +
  geom_alluvium(
    aes(fill = Class), show.legend=FALSE,
    width = 0, knot.pos = 0, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(
    stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),
    reverse = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Survived", "Sex", "Class"))
```

[image]

You can refactor any of the columns and use `levels=` to specify the ordering:

```
df <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
df$Class <- factor(df$Class, levels=c("2nd", "Crew", "1st", "3rd"))

ggplot(df, aes(y = Freq, axis1 = Survived, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Class)) +
  geom_alluvium(
    aes(fill = Class), show.legend=FALSE,
    width = 0, knot.pos = 0, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(
    stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),
    reverse = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Survived", "Sex", "Class"))
```

[image]

### Addendum (OP request)

OP requested some follow up questions that are pretty straightforward:

1. How do you change the label of the stratum (ex. "Survived" "Sex" and "Class" in the example)?
2. How do you specify a set of colors for the alluvials?

The strata are mapped on a continuous x axis in the final plot.  Consequently, you approach *renaming* the strata the same way you would approach relabeling tick marks on the x axis via `scale_x_continuous()` and specifying `breaks=` and `labels=` arguments.

For color, you can specify colors using `scale_fill_manual()` and supplying the `values=` argument.  For manual specification, it's important that the length of the vector sent to `values=` matches the number of different things mapped to the fill aesthetic.  If specifying hex color codes, you need to specify in the format `"#XXXXXX"` as a character, starting with a pound sign `"#"`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = Freq, axis1 = Survived, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Class)) +
  geom_alluvium(
    aes(fill = Class), show.legend=FALSE,
    width = 0, knot.pos = 0, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(
    stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),
    reverse = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Example Label", "Sex", "Class")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#2E9599","#F7DC68","#F46C3F", "#A7226F"))
```

[image]

*Note: if you want to specifically assign a particular color to a particular alluvial, you can use a named vector.  So, something like the following applies colors specifically:*

```
scale_fill_manual(
  values = c(
    "1st" = "red",
    "2nd" = "blue",
    "3rd" = "yellow",
    "Crew" = "green"))
```

Comment: Your answer solved my problem, thank you very much friend！May I ask you 2 more question? 1. Do you know how can I add label under each axis? Such as Surivived/Sex/Class as the example graph showed. 2.How can I customize ribbon color? such as 2E9599,F7DC68,F46C3F and A7226F

Comment: OP, I added the answer to your follow up questions as an edit to the original post.